# How to remove this special type of action

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my Parent theme, there is an action hook that i like to remove:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( $this, 'proceed_to_checkout' ), 10 );
```

and i like to remove this action from child theme, i have tried following 3 things, none is working so far:

1. `remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( $this,
   'proceed_to_checkout' ), 10 );`
2. `remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'proceed_to_checkout', 10 );`
3. I create a file **foobar.php** inside my **child-theme**, then include it in **functions.php**

this is the code of **foobar.php**

```
<?php 

class Foobar extends Parent_Woocommerce {

    public function __construct() {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( $this, 'proceed_to_checkout' ), 10 );
        }
public function proceed_to_checkout() {
    return ;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Look here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/remove-action-or-remove-filter-with-external-classes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys, following is what worked for me:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'koko', 99);
//add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'koko', 99); this action not worked 
function koko() {
    global $parent_woocommerce;
    // remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( 'Parent_Woocommerce', 'proceed_to_checkout' ), 10 ); class name trick not working here
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', array( $parent_woocommerce, 'proceed_to_checkout' ), 10 );
}
```